# Publishing on Google Cloud Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

While deploying a VM solution on Google Cloud Marketplace, is it mandatory to use its password autogeneration feature?

Can I not publish my solution on marketplace without password autogeneration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that for security reasons you cannot use a default password and ask users to change it, and that there's an admin portal used in your solution, the password should be randomly generated for each instance.

If this is the case,then you wouldn't be able to publish your solution on Marketplace without the password automatically-generated.

Here is the information that I found:

[Image & deployment - Component - Admin Password](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm-testing-guidelines#image_deployment)

[Setting and retrieving application user credentials](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/technical-components#setting_and_retrieving_application_user_credentials)